# Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri) and MultiView1.SetActiveView

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiview

I have a submit form. when user click save button it should set active view of multiview1 to view2. I added Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri); to prohibit users from pressing F5 button and submitting the form again and again, but it causes to multiview1 not set active view to view2 and after submiting the form still shows view1

```
protected void btnSubmitAd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
        {

        Ads ad = new Ads
            {
                Title = txtAdTitle.Text,
                Dec = txtAdText.Text,
                Name = txtName.Text,
                Email = txtEmail.Text

            };

            context.Ads.Add(ad);
            context.SaveChanges();

            MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

    }
}
```

and this is my  pageload event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);
        }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve after redirect?

Comment: Nothing When user submit the form Multiview1's active view should set to view1.

Comment: Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri); is to stop users from Resubmiting the same form by refreshing the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will always set the view to View1.

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
  {
      MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);
  }
```

If you want to set the `ActiveView` to a specific view after the redirect then you have set your view information somewhere. like `Session` or `QueryString`

Query string code will be like:

```
protected void btnSubmitAd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {

        Ads ad = new Ads
        {
            Title = txtAdTitle.Text,
            Dec = txtAdText.Text,
            Name = txtName.Text,
            Email = txtEmail.Text

        };

        context.Ads.Add(ad);
        context.SaveChanges();

        //MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);  No need for that as it will be lost after redirect... 

        //Append your ActiveView information in query string with Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "?activeView=View2");// 

     }
}
```

And on `PageLoad`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
        {
            string activeView = Request.QueryString["activeView"]
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(activeView) && activeView == "View2")
                MultiView1.SetActiveView(View2);
            else 
                MultiView1.SetActiveView(View1);
        }
}
```